# Diseño en un grafico de R usando ggplot

Tags: r, rstudio, ggplot2, packages, design

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
ggplot(data = datos, aes(x = w_1stWon, y = w_1stIn)) + 
 geom_point(shape = 16, color = "black", size = 4) +
  geom_point(shape = 16, color = "yellow", size = 3) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", color = "blue", linetype = "solid", size = 1) +
  labs(x = "Primer servicio ganado", y = "Primer servicio adentro") +
  ggtitle("Regresión Lineal primer servicio ganado por primer servicio adentro") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  theme_light(base_size = 10, base_line_size = 0.5, base_rect_size = 1)
```

Lo que busco lograr es que los puntos sean pelotas de tenis. Casi que lo logro pero queda un poco raro. No se si existe alguna manera mas facil de lograr esto, o algun paquete que simplifique esto.´

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No uses `shape` aprovecha directamente el circulo que ya dibuja `geom_point()`. Esto mejora bastante tu intento previo.

```
  geom_point(color = "black", size = 5, alpha=.1) + # Una sombra que suaviza el contorno
  geom_point(color = "black", size = 4) +           # El borde negro
  geom_point(color = "yellow", size = 3) +          # El fondo amarillo
```

La otra posibilidad es usar [`ggimage`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggimage/index.html) y con `geom_image()` usar alguna imagen de pelota de tenis.